# How to perform cvs checkout by release tag name in Hudson?

Tags: cvs, hudson

Under Hudson, does somebody know how to specify a release tag name in a cvs checkout ?

At the moment, i only specify the CVSROOT and modules names to checkout my project in my workspace. I tried to add '-r TAG_NAME' for each module name, but it doesn't work.

I think that this functionality exist, so if someone as the right syntax/way to do it.. :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: What error do you get from the CVS checkout that Hudson performs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project's CVS configuration, there's a *Branch* field and a checkbox labeled, "This is a tag, not a branch". You should enter your release tag in the *Branch* field (without `-r`) and check the checkbox.

Comment: Exact.
But in case of multiple checkout in the same job it doesn't work. I fear this field work only for a simple checkout.
Another question: in case of a checkout in only one project, i tried to parameterized the release tag name without success ($param_name, %param_name% or ${param_name} syntaxes are not replaced by the value in the Branch field)
Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: @kij, it works for me with multiple modules listed in the configuration. What error do you get?

Comment: In the Module(s) field, i enter 2 module names, one per line.
In the Branch field i can enter only on release tag name, if i try to enter more release names (one per module names in the Module(s) field), it goes in error as it retrieve all the content of the Branch as one release tag name, and not several. (no parsing process for this field ?)
So the error message is something like "unknown release tag".

Giving multiple module names without any release tag works fine, it fails only with release option.

Comment: Re,
Finally, i made a batch script that take module and release name as parameters and checkout the given module with or without release option, depending on the presence (or non presence) of the release name parameter.
And then, i execute this script for each modules to checkout.
Finally it's a better solution for me, but i still want to know why i can't checkout severall module by release name with the CVS interface of Hudson.

Comment: @kij, OK, now I understand. You're trying to checkout different modules with different release tags. The CVS plugin doesn't support that. Sounds like you have a workaround, but you could always submit a feature request: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: New feature have been submitted. Thanks.